# Creating deep links with History_API

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I am trying to pull deep linking. I have found one tutorial and tried to implement it.  Here is my History_API with jQuery/Ajax loader:

```
$('.hor_menu').click(function() {
    var url = $(this).attr('href');
    $.ajax({
        url: url + '?ajax=1',
        success: function(data) {
            $('#destination').html(data);
        }
    });
```

So if any `div`-button with `.hor_menu` class clicked, Ajax loads it's contents to a `#destination` block.

The link is changed with:

```
if (url != window.location) {
    window.history.pushState(null, null, url);
}
return false;
});
```

To make Back/Forward buttons activated I use:

```
$(window).bind('popstate', function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: location.pathname + '?ajax=1',
        success: function(data) {
            $('#destination').html(data);
        }
    });
});
```

Sample `div` button:

```
<div class="hor_menu" id="b5" href="/pages/about.htm" onclick="
    ('main_hor_menu')"><strong>About us</strong></div>
```

The whole thing works fine: changes the links, loads the requests to a destination. When I click back/forward browser reloads content only as it should. The only issue is that I didn't achieve deep links: in any state, pressing F5 reloads the requested page, not it's contents to a `#destination` block. And, obviously, I can not make direct link to any page. Please, tell me what I have missed or did wrong.

Comment: Back/Forward button of browsers is not coordinated on Ajax

Comment: you can have your error page bounce them back to the app and use the reefer to tell what URL they arrived with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This kind of statefull client side apps is really hard to do without a router component such as [backbone's](http://backbonejs.org/#Router) or [ember's](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Router.html).
I recommend finding one you like and use it instead of building your own router.

Also, make sure that your server router maps `pages/**` (or whatever is relevant) to your html file

Comment: a JS-based router like that won't help, the server needs to actually serve all urls used by the client to allow seamless refreshing/bookmarking. if that's not feasible, use hash navigation. yes, you have to double-code the front and back, it's not a SPA, like hash-based-nav apps use...

Comment: Looking at the code samples, a router is exactly the missing bit. he needs a state machine that knows how to map a specific path to an ajax call and vice versa .

Comment: yes, but without a server-side routing platform (not bb/ember), the client-side router code would never run when the special url is refreshed, instead a 404 would show... the tough part of the history API is implementing the server-side support; it's easy with node.js, but hard with "traditional" webservers that want pre-defined URL paths.

Comment: Oh, yaeh, good point. yes, the server side router should map  `pages/**` to the save html page

Comment: Thanks for suggestions. I think I'm in trouble=) Still, Ember's router is simple a bit more than BB's.